C# Access Denied while calling GetPrinter WIn API
I have only basic knowledge on C# but I have a requirement to modify printer settings like Orientation/Copies. I have written the code as below, but it throws the error "Access is Denied". I have given "Manage This Printer" access to the logged-In user but still I receive this error. Please help to resolve the issue. I'm using "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer for this example since no printer driver is installed.

//Code

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Modify_Printer_Settings {
  internal class Program {

    //Class for OpenPrinter -> PRINTERDEFAULTS arugument
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal class PrinterDefault {
      public IntPtr pDatatype;
      public IntPtr pDevMode;
      public int DesiredAccess;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PRINTER_INFO_2 {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pServerName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPrinterName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pShareName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPortName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDriverName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pComment;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pLocation;
      public IntPtr pDevMode;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pSepFile;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pPrintProcessor;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDatatype;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pParameters;
      public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;
      public Int32 Attributes;
      public Int32 Priority;
      public Int32 DefaultPriority;
      public Int32 StartTime;
      public Int32 UntilTime;
      public Int32 Status;
      public Int32 cJobs;
      public Int32 AveragePPM;
    }

    private const short CCDEVICENAME = 32;
    private const short CCFORMNAME = 32;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEVMODE {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCDEVICENAME)]
      public string dmDeviceName;
      public short dmSpecVersion;
      public short dmDriverVersion;
      public short dmSize;
      public short dmDriverExtra;
      public int dmFields;
      public short dmOrientation;
      public short dmPaperSize;
      public short dmPaperLength;
      public short dmPaperWidth;
      public short dmScale;
      public short dmCopies;
      public short dmDefaultSource;
      public short dmPrintQuality;
      public short dmColor;
      public short dmDuplex;
      public short dmYResolution;
      public short dmTTOption;
      public short dmCollate;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCFORMNAME)]
      public string dmFormName;
      public short dmUnusedPadding;
      public short dmBitsPerPel;
      public int dmPelsWidth;
      public int dmPelsHeight;
      public int dmDisplayFlags;
      public int dmDisplayFrequency;
    }

    //Win API Definitions
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet =                         CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
    private static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, PrinterDefault pDefault);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "GetPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool GetPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 dwLevel, IntPtr pPrinter, Int32 dwBuf, out Int32 dwNeeded);

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, int Level, IntPtr pPrinter, int Command);

    //Printer Access variables
    private
    const int PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x4;
    private
    const int PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x8;
    private
    const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
    private
    const int PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | PRINTER_ACCESS_USE);
    private static string printer = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
    private static IntPtr PrinterHandle;
    private static IntPtr pPrinterInfo;
    private static IntPtr ptrDEVMODE;

    private static PRINTER_INFO_2 sPrinter_Info = new PRINTER_INFO_2();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      SetPrinterSettings();
    }

    private static void SetPrinterSettings() {
      DEVMODE sDEVMODE;

      sDEVMODE = GetPrinterSettings();
      sDEVMODE.dmOrientation = 2; //Landscape

      Marshal.StructureToPtr(sDEVMODE, ptrDEVMODE, true);

      sPrinter_Info.pDevMode = ptrDEVMODE;
      sPrinter_Info.pSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

      Marshal.StructureToPtr(sPrinter_Info, pPrinterInfo, true);

      int iRet = Convert.ToInt16(SetPrinter(PrinterHandle, 2, pPrinterInfo, 0));
      if (iRet == 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
      }
    }

    private static DEVMODE GetPrinterSettings() {
      int iBytesNeeded, itmp;
      DEVMODE sDEVMODE;

      var pDefault = new PrinterDefault {
        pDatatype = IntPtr.Zero,
          pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero,
          DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER
      };

      int iRet = Convert.ToInt32(OpenPrinter(printer, out PrinterHandle, pDefault));
      if (iRet == 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
      }

      GetPrinter(PrinterHandle, 2, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out iBytesNeeded);
      if (iBytesNeeded <= 0) {
        throw new System.Exception("Unable to allocate memory");
      } else {
        // Allocate enough space for PRINTER_INFO_2...
        pPrinterInfo = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(iBytesNeeded);
        pPrinterInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(iBytesNeeded);

        iRet = Convert.ToInt32(GetPrinter(PrinterHandle, 2, pPrinterInfo, iBytesNeeded, out itmp));`Here the error occurs`
        if (iRet == 0) {
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        //Get the Printer Info strucure
            sPrinter_Info = (PRINTER_INFO_2) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pPrinterInfo,             typeof(PRINTER_INFO_2));

        //Get the DEVMODE strucure
        ptrDEVMODE = sPrinter_Info.pDevMode;
        sDEVMODE = (DEVMODE) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrDEVMODE, typeof (DEVMODE));

        return sDEVMODE;
      }

    }
  }
}

//Code ends....



Your question looks good, but is there any chance you could edit your question to share the line on which the exception is thrown as well as the full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exceptions, if any? That information could help us to diagnose your problem. Thanks!
